# matlab multithreaded functions

Tags: multithreading, matlab

"sort" is one of the built-in functions in matlab(R2010a) that takes advantage of
multithreading. When I use "sort" on a large matrix, on a machine with
8 cores, I can see that all the cores are activated but the reported
cpu usage for each is never above 25%. While my own openmp "mex" fully
employs all the cores.
Is there a way of forcing matlab to use all ?

Thanks in advance,

Kamran

Comment: Is your mex faster than MATLABs sort?

Comment: No, slightly slower. I don't do any advance sorting in mex. But it's cpu usage is 100% on all cores.

Answer (score 3):

That does not mean that threads in your code work all the time, while in MATLAB threads don't work so much. You may spin (active wait) on some locks/mutexes inside the code (`#pragma omp barrier`), while matlab's threads may be sleeping. The effect is the same - threads wait, but in your case you will see 100% cpu usage.

MATLAB does not have a switch saying 'use 100% of the cpu'. This is decided by the OS. If threads have work, they run. From your description I'd say threads in matlabs sort sleep often.

So whatever MATLAB does, it at least tries to do the best it can. If you are almost as fast as matlab - congrats! good for you :)